# How to disable the Details panel in Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In Win10, how do I suppress this details panel completely?

[image: details panel]

I *never* need it, and it drives me crazy how it suppresses columns I require (like date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "View" tab.
- Deselect "Details Pane".

[image]

Comment: 1. Open the all users, specific users or groups, or all users except administrators Local Group Policy Editor for how you want this policy applied.

2. In the left pane, click/tap on to expand User Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Windows Explorer, and open Explorer Frame Pane. 

3. In the right pane of Explorer Frame Pane, double click/tap on Turn off Details Pane. 

4. To Disable Windows Explorer "Details Pane" 
5. You can now close the Local Group Policy Editor window if you like.